# Join 2 table using lambda and updating model

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, lambda, entity-framework-6

```
  var list = oSIM.Issues.Join(db.IssueTracker_Read,
  c => c.IssueId,
   o => o.issueid,
  (c, o) => new
  {
    c.read = o.issueid==null?false:true;
  });
```

This is some pseudo code that doesn't work but should convey my requirement.

Entity of Issues is of type `Issue` which has many fields. I want to update `Issue.Read` to true if there is a linked record in `IssueTracker_Read` record.

The returned collection should be list but with `list[x].read` to be updated based on a linked record.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var list = oSIM.Issues.GroupJoin(db.IssueTracker_Read,
 c => c.IssueId,
 o => o.issueid,
 (c, o) => new
 {
    Issue = c,
    IssueRead = o.DefaultIfEmpty()
 }).Select(groupJoinInfo=> new { 
       groupJoinInfo.Issue,
       Read = groupJoinInfo.IssueRead != null && groupJoinInfo.IssueRead.Any()
     });
```

And then you can iterate through the returned collection and update the Issues with the new `Read` property from the anonymous object.

`GroupJoin` performs an left join between the tables.

**Edit**

Added missing `new`, thanks user2520306.

**Edit 2**

Added a  new condition for the Read property, this should return correctly.

Comment: var list = oSIM.Issues.GroupJoin(db.IssueTracker_Read,
                 c => c.IssueId,
                 o => o.issueid,
                 (c, o) => new
                 {
                     Issue = c,
                     IssueRead = o.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 }).Select(groupJoinInfo => {
                     groupJoinInfo.Issue;       Read = groupJoinInfo.IssueRead != null  //get error 'Read' doesn't exist in current context
                
                     });

Comment: that's compiled fine and this is the final solution but item.Read is always true.

             

                foreach(var item in list)
                {
                    item.Issue.Read = item.Read; //always returning true?

                }